# SSL for logged in users?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, standards

For a website which offers free content and paid content (when the user is logged in), should it operate over SSL (i.e. https)?

More to the point- for pages other than the registration page, there is sometimes content like facebook like, third-party banners, etc. When I view those pages in various browsers, I get warnings that the page is not completely secure, since some of the content is unprotected.

Is there a standard for this, and reasons why?

I've noticed, for example, that gmail keeps it over https while facebook opts for http...

Comment: BTW, the warning isn't saying that the certificate is invalid; it's saying that the page is not completely secure.

Comment: Thanks SLaks... can you look at https://tjandpals.com and let me know if I'm getting the best possible warning?

Comment: I don't see any warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first question: you should consider using HTTPS for your website for user authentication and their usage once authenticated, because most authentication methods (typically cookie-based, session-ID in the URL or HTTP Basic) would transmit the authentication token (e.g. the cookie) in clear otherwise. As such, an eavesdropper could impersonate the authenticated user by re-using the session-ID/cookie for themselves. This sort of attack has been around for a long time, but tools like Firesheep, in conjunction with the use of unprotected (possibly public) WiFi networks makes this quite practical unfortunately.

Regarding the second question: you get those warnings for mixed-content, i.e. pages served over HTTPS that embed content from HTTP sites. If you're using secure cookies, your authentication token (in the cookie) shouldn't leak to the non-protected content embedded on the page... However, it's impossible for the use to know that. Teaching users to ignore warnings is generally bad practice.
If it's your content, turn on HTTPS. If it's someone else's and they don't have HTTPS access, it's a bit trickier. One solution may be to relay their content through your website (but you would need to rewrite their links, etc.).

As always, it's a matter of risk assessment. You can actually use Facebook over HTTPS (by typing `https://` explicitly). Since [posting on Facebook can have you sent to prison](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-15347868), you wouldn't want anyone impersonating you.

Some sites don't enable HTTPS because it's thought to be expensive, which [isn't necessarily true](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/02/06/stillinexpensive.html) (Compatibility of XP for Server Name Indication and shared hosting is also an issue, as detailed in this article too).

Comment: I would add that even registration page itself would need to be protected.

Comment: Thanks- so basically, sticking with https is good and users/browser-makers just need to deal with the warning? :)

Comment: @davidkomer: no, that's the problem. Don't make the user deal with the warning: make sure everything on the page comes from HTTPS too.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is computationally expensive; serving pages over SSL will make your site a little slower (especially with lots of traffic).  (you can replace the computational expense with financial expense by buying separate SSL hardware)

Gmail serves everything under SSL because they believe that all of your email content is confidential.
Basically, they think that email needs to be more secure than Facebook.

Comment: http://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/02/06/stillinexpensive.html

Comment: @Bruno: great article, I wonder why it's not linked to in your answer ;-)

Comment: This is incorrect. The reason gmail and facebook use SSL everywhere is so that someone can't sniff your authentication cookie and then impersonate you. There are some really easy tools for this. E.g. [firesheep][1]


  [1]: http://codebutler.com/firesheep

Comment: @imichaelmiers: I know, but that doesn't explain why some websites don't use HTTPS.